# Building 3D CNN for binary classification of greyscale MRI data, Data dimensionality issue when attempting model.fit

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, mri, medical-imaging

I'm trying to build a 3D CNN for binary classification of greyscale MRI data. I'm new to this, so don't pull any punches, I'm here to learn! I have a subsample of 20 3D files, with dimensions (189, 233, 197). I add a a dimension to act as the channel using np.reshape to get (189, 233, 197, 1). I use tf.shape to get the shape of the dataset, which is

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(5,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([ 20, 189, 233, 197,   1], dtype=int32)>
```

and the same on the label data which is

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([20], dtype=int32)>
```

Below is the full code that I'm using:

```
import numpy as np
import glob
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import glob

import SimpleITK as sitk

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')

datapath = ('/content/gdrive/My Drive/DirectoryTest/All Data/')
patients = os.listdir(datapath)
labels_df = pd.read_csv('/content/Data_Index.csv', index_col = 0 )

FullDataSet = []

for patient in patients:
  a = sitk.ReadImage(datapath + patient)
  b = sitk.GetArrayFromImage(a)
  c = np.reshape(b, (189,233,197))
  FullDataSet.append(c)

labelset = []

for i in patients:
  label = labels_df.loc[i, 'Group']
  if label == 'AD':  # use `==` instead of `is` to compare strings
    labelset.append(0.)
  elif label == 'CN':
    labelset.append(1.)
  else:
      raise "Oops, unknown label" 

labelset = np.array(labelset)

x_train, x_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(FullDataSet, labelset, train_size=0.75)

## 3D CNN

CNN_model = tf.keras.Sequential(
  [
      #tf.keras.layers.Reshape([189, 233, 197, 1], input_shape=[189, 233, 197]), 
      tf.keras.layers.Input(shape =[ 189, 233, 197, 1] ),                       
      tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(kernel_size=(7, 7, 7), filters=32, activation='relu',
                          padding='same', strides=(3, 3, 3)),
      #tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
      tf.keras.layers.MaxPool3D(pool_size=(3, 3, 3), padding='same'),
      tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.20),
      
      tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(kernel_size=(5, 5, 5), filters=64, activation='relu',
                          padding='same', strides=(3, 3, 3)),
      #tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
      tf.keras.layers.MaxPool3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2), padding='same'),
      tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.20),

      tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), filters=128, activation='relu',
                          padding='same', strides=(1, 1, 1)),
      #tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
      tf.keras.layers.MaxPool3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2), padding='same'),
      tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.20), 

      # last activation could be either sigmoid or softmax, need to look into this more. Sig for binary output, Soft for multi output 
      tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),   
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.20),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')

  ])
# Compile the model
CNN_model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.00001), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# print model layers
CNN_model.summary()

CNN_history = CNN_model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, validation_data=[x_valid, y_valid])
```

When I attempt to fit the model the dimensionality doesn't seem to line up and I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-c698c45a4d36> in <module>()
      1 #running of the model
      2 #CNN_history = CNN_model.fit(dataset_train, epochs=100, validation_data =dataset_test, validation_steps=1)
----> 3 CNN_history = CNN_model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, validation_data=[x_valid, y_valid], batch_size = 1)
      4 
      5 

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    106   def _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
    107     if not self._in_multi_worker_mode():  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 108       return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    109 
    110     # Running inside `run_distribute_coordinator` already.

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1061           use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing,
   1062           model=self,
-> 1063           steps_per_execution=self._steps_per_execution)
   1064 
   1065       # Container that configures and calls `tf.keras.Callback`s.

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in __init__(self, x, y, sample_weight, batch_size, steps_per_epoch, initial_epoch, epochs, shuffle, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, model, steps_per_execution)
   1115         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing,
   1116         distribution_strategy=ds_context.get_strategy(),
-> 1117         model=model)
   1118 
   1119     strategy = ds_context.get_strategy()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in __init__(self, x, y, sample_weights, sample_weight_modes, batch_size, epochs, steps, shuffle, **kwargs)
    280             label, ", ".join(str(i.shape[0]) for i in nest.flatten(data)))
    281       msg += "Please provide data which shares the same first dimension."
--> 282       raise ValueError(msg)
    283     num_samples = num_samples.pop()
    284 

ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 189
  y sizes: 15
Please provide data which shares the same first dimension.
```

The training split is set to 0.75 so 15 of the 20. I'm confused why this isn't working and can't figure out why this is the input the model is receiving. I have had some help previously, and using the following code to create a dummy set results in a model that will run:

```
train_size = 20
val_size = 5

X_train = np.random.random([train_size, 189, 233, 197]).astype(np.float32)
X_valid = np.random.random([val_size, 189, 233, 197]).astype(np.float32)
y_train = np.random.randint(2, size=train_size).astype(np.float32)
y_valid = np.random.randint(2, size=val_size).astype(np.float32)
```

I've been hitting my head against the wall for a while on this one. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Writing here first because I'm ''almost'' certain of the issue, but not completely, can you try changing you validation_data to `validation_data = (x_valid, y_valid)`, i.e. using parenthesis rather than square brackets ?

Comment: Thanks for the input @dm2! I tried that with the same results unfortunately.

Comment: yeah was going to say, there's something else I'm not seeing because the error would be different (although keep the changes, it should be a tuple)

Comment: I will, thanks. I think there might be an issue around the batch size and the first dimension of the data, in this case 189, and its using that as the batch size or something. Obviously I'm not sure, but the fact that the toy data works is what confuses me the most, as my data looks the same as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have commenting privileges at this time, otherwise I would, as this might not be a full answer, that said:

When I try creating a toy 4-dimensional dataset, and then appending it to a list (to add a channel - which is what I believe you have done?), the shape I get is not (dim1, dim2, dim3, dim4, channel) but (channel, dim1, dim2, dim3, dim4). I've included a worked example below:

```
import numpy as np

df = np.arange(0,625).reshape(5,5,5,5)
print(df.shape) # returns (5,5,5,5)

lst = []
lst.append(df)

print(np.asarray(g).shape) # returns (1,5,5,5,5)
```

Based on this, could it be that the shape of your data would actually be (1, 189, 233, 197) not (189, 233, 197, 1) as you intended?

In addition, the error message to me seems to be implying as if you are not passing the same number of samples for X and y?

```
ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 189
  y sizes: 15
Please provide data which shares the same first dimension.
```

Typically the input to a network will have identical first sizes (and stealing your own toy dataset as an example, and running):

```
print(X_train.shape, y_train_shape, X_test.shape, y_test.shape)
# returns: (20, 189, 233, 197), (20,) (5, 189, 233, 197) (5,)
```

They match because then this essentially means that each sample corresponds to a label and vice versa. It seems to me as if the error message is stating that the first dimension of each is 189 and 15 for your X and y inputs, respectively. Could you double-check the shapes immediately prior to inputting to the network?

Comment: Thanks for the input @gmiles! You were correct in that appending to the list added in the fashion you specified, so if I add 20 files it would be (20, 189, 233, 197). The shape I need is  (20, 189, 233, 197,  1), as the 1 would take the channel dimension for the grey scale image, and the 20 is the batch size. This issue is that when build the FullDataSet, I convert to an np array and add this data to the list. Because the labelset is an np array they are incompatible so I need to convert FullDataSet to an np array after everything is appended to the list and it seems to run! 

Thanks again!